# Postgres 9.6 (pgAdmin 4) - How to query daily statistics

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, pgadmin

Is there a way I can query through pgAdmin in a way I will get statistics for daily query usage?

I need to find what queries are run against my api as I get huge network traffic. I'm looking for a way I can get top queries for example (top 100). I've tried using various pg statistics, but didn't find anything that provides this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension [pg_stat_statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstatstatements.html) is what you are looking for.  It is not provided by PgAdmin4, but you can use PgAdmin4 to read from the view it creates.  It provides cumulative stats, so you either need to reset them every night, or just save daily snapshots and compute the differences.  You might want to use [PgAgent](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/pgagent_install.html?highlight=pgagent) to automate some of this.  (I have no experience with PgAgent, I just know that it exists.  I use crontab to schedule things)

Comment: Superb, just what I needed and worked perfectly! I've followed https://pganalyze.com/docs/install/amazon_rds/01_configure_rds_instance this to set it on rds.